# UITextDropDelegate willPerformDrop is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to implement drag and drop feature for UITextView. I have set the delegate\

```
textView.dropDelegate = self
```

and implemented

```
func textDroppableView(_ textDroppableView: UIView & UITextDroppable, willPerformDrop drop: UITextDropRequest)
```

But the ablove delegate is not getting called. Other delgate functions like dropSessionDidEnter and dropSessionDidEnd seems to be getting called.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
class className: UIViewController{
override func viewDidLoad{
super.viewDidLoad()
textView.delegate = self
}

}
extension className: UITextDropDelegate{
func textDroppableView(_ textDroppableView: UIView & UITextDroppable, 
willPerformDrop drop: UITextDropRequest){
//perform actions here.
}
}
```